# fileupload click event doesnt get fired properly after applying certain css styles (On IE 8)

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, .net

I have the following

Asp.net Markup

```
 <div class="formSample">
        <div class="uploadTest">
            Choose File 
        <asp:FileUpload ID="uploadControl" runat="server" />
        </div>          
 </div>
```

Class CLass

.formSample

```
{
   display: inline-block;
   float: right;
   width: 22em;
   margin-top: 0.3em;
}
```

.uploadTest

```
 {
   font-family: 'open_sansregular', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   float: right;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 9em;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
   background: #22a0db;
   cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.4em 0.2em 0.1em 0.3em;
     margin: 0em 0em;
    border-radius: 1em;
   -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1em;
    -ms-border-radius: 1em;
    -o-border-radius: 1em;
}
```

Javascript

```
    function upLoadOnClick() {
        document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_uploadControl').parentNode.click();
    }

      document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_uploadControl').onClick = upLoadOnClick;
```

The issue here is when i press the control on the right hand side then only the pop up appears but when i press the control on middle or left the browse window doesnt fire up. This problem only occurs in IE8.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all, most (and probably all modern) browsers do not allow programmatic clicks of `file` inputs for security reasons, so your javascript will not work the way you want it to. To get the select file popup to appear the user must click the control themselves. Your code as-is without the javascript seems to work as expected for me in both Chrome and Firefox. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tc8nb9sp/).

The `file` input is notoriously difficult to style across browsers. The most common approach I believe is to make the file input invisible and overlay it on top of other elements that are styled the way you want them to look. Here's another example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbqpdutf/1/).

Comment: Hi Rudism. Thank you for your comment. Have you tried running the above contents on IE8? My apologies for not explaining the browser version. If you try to run it on IE8 this issue will become crystal clear.